# Mongoose Queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a mongoose query that deals with nested data.

Example of data:

```
{
  name : 'blah',
  en : {
    state : 'published',
    pubDate : '2015-10-19-22T13:44:16.387Z'
  },
  es : {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I want to query the date for all objects with a publication date (`pubDate`) earlier than today or blank. My Schema has the `pubDate` nested by language (`en`, `es`, etc.)

My application has a `locals` object that stores some useful values: for this purpose I have `locals.today` which maps to today's date as well as `locals.lang` which maps to the users' currently selected language.

Using mongoose I can query for an individual parameter using where:

```
.where(locals.lang + '.pubDate').lt(locals.today)
```

What I can't seem to accomplish is to use the or query operator as it doesn't recognize the locals object inside of it.

```
.or([
  { locals.lang + '.pubDate' : { '$lt' : locals.today } },
  { locals.lang + '.pubDate' : '' }
])
```

I can confirm that this syntax works if I hardcode the language portion (`'en.pubDate'` instead of `locals.lang + '.pubDate'`) but this is not a viable solution in my application. Also I have tried setting up a new variable (`var publicationdate = locals.lang + '.pubDate'`) but that does not work either. It seems the syntax does not like having a variable for the property name.

Does anyone know how I can use the variables within the `or` query syntax in mongoose?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **[`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)** to create object properties on the fly, you can set up the query objects as follows:

```
var firstObj = {},
    secondObj = {};

firstObj[locals.lang + '.pubDate'] = { '$lt' : locals.today };
secondObj[locals.lang + '.pubDate'] = '';
```

which you can then use as:

```
.or([ firstObj, secondObj ])
```